# How to logout and logon session immediately in quickfix python

Tags: python, quickfix

I'm using `quickfix` with python bindings and I need to log out of a current session and re-logon again immediately. But I'm having the following issues.

- If I call `session.logout()` followed immediately by `session.logon()`, it never logs out because I think these methods are just setting some flags.
- I tried calling `session.generateLogout()` but this doesn't actually have a swig binding, so can't be called from python.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to do it manually ? Quickfix handles it perfectly well using the parameters in the config file.Better change you config file, rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: Apologies for not providing some context. I'm writing a feed handler accepting data over a fix connection. Under certain circumstances, the downstream components are not available to process data and I need to be terminate the FIX connection, reinitialise downstream components and then relogon.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the logout request hasn't been fulfilled before you try to logon. Try reacting to the onlogout method with a relogon message based on certain conditions.